# I can't seem to get this JQuery slideshow to work

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I've been following tutorials, because I wanted to learn how to make an image carousel/slideshow on my own, but I can't seem to get any to work. This one is the one the makes the most sense so far, but it's still not working. Would anyone be able to help?

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NLDAX/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <ul>
        <li><img class="slide" src="http://i.imgur.com/zjynAaQ.jpg"  /></li>
        <li><img class="slide" src="http://i.imgur.com/jxHZA2o.jpg"  /></li>
        <li><img class="slide" src="http://i.imgur.com/zn6DmkV.jpg"  /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#slideshow {
    width: 804px;
    height: 312px;
    margin: 100px auto 50px auto;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
    width: 100%;
}

#slideshow li {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 8;
}

#slideshow img.active {
    z-index: 10;
}

#slideshow img.last-active {
    z-index: 9;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // settings
      var $slider = $('#slideshow ul'); // class or id of carousel slider
      var $slide = '#slideshow li'; // could also use 'img' if you're not using a ul
      var $transition_time = 1000; // 1 second
      var $time_between_slides = 4000; // 4 seconds

      function slides(){
        return $slider.find($slide);
      }

      slides().fadeOut();

      // set active classes
      slides().first().addClass('active');
      slides().first().fadeIn($transition_time);

      // auto scroll 
      $interval = setInterval(
        function(){
          var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

          slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
          slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

          if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start

          slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
          slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
        }
        , $transition_time +  $time_between_slides 
      );

});
```

Comment: it helps to mention *which* tutorial doesn't work, and in what way your attempts aren't work if you're not going to show the code or give a link to your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that you're trying to do `$slider.find($slide)` but the selector for `$slide` references an id `#slideshow` that isn't inside the `ul` element represented by `$slider`.

The solution is to just fix your selector for `$slide` so that it is relative to the `ul`.  In this case referencing `li` is just fine.

```
var $slide = 'li';
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NLDAX/1/)